# How do I pass the current user id as a hidden field in a Django form?

Tags: django, forms, hidden

The problem I'm having is I'm trying to create a form which passes the currently logged-in users ID by embedding it within a hidden field in a ModelForm.

My model:

```
class Portfolios(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    port_name = models.CharField(max_length=135, blank=True)
    port_type = models.ForeignKey(PortType, null=True, db_column='port_type', blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.port_name;

class Meta:
    db_table = u'tbl_portfolios'
```

My form:

```
class PortfoliosCreateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Portfolios;
```

My template:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="create_form_field">
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Create" /></p>
</form>
```

I call the template using a generic create view:

```
url(
    r'^portfolios/create/$',
    'django.views.generic.create_update.create_object',
    dict(
        form_class=PortfoliosCreateForm,
        post_save_redirect='/',
        template_name='portfolios/create.html'
    )
```

),

How can I best embed the user ID within that form so it's passed a hidden field? Or should I simply pass in a dummy field and fill the value in within a custom save function?

Edit: The User model is the in-built Django User model.

Thanks

Comment: are you using the built in User model? when you say 'current user id' to me that indicates that your app is somehow aware of the user already, if this is the case passing it on the form should be unecessary?

Comment: I am using the built in User model, yes. When the form is submitted, the user must be logged into the system, so in that sense the app is aware of the user already. I don't know where to retrieve the user ID so it may be saved as part of the record.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is much safer to get the current user from the request after the form has been submitted. You could rewrite the generic view to something like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render

def create_portfolio(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PortfoliosCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            portfolio = form.save(commit=False)
            portfolio.user = request.user  # The logged-in user
            portfolio.save()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = PortfoliosCreateForm()
    return render(request, 'portfolios/create.html', {'form': form})


url(r'^portfolios/create/$', create_portfolio)


class PortfoliosCreateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Portfolios;
        exclude = ['user']   # Will be taken from the request
```

Comment: @JakubRoztočil please see my answer below.

Answer (score -3):

Setting all in the generic view is NOT a good practice because:

1. it forces you to change the logic in the `form` class, which can adds constraints holes, so you can save **bad** data to the database IF you will try to create an object someplace outside on the generic view, and
2. it adds extra useless complexity to the generic view. The view is like a controller, it should know WHO is in charge for validating/saving the data and just delegate it to that party. It should NOT know HOW objects are related and validated, and
3. it forces you to distribute your code here and there.

On my opinion the better approach might be:

#### model

```
class Book(models.Model):
    # ...
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, related_name='books')

    # ...
```

#### form

```
class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Book
    # ...

    widgets = {
        'author': forms.HiddenInput(),
        # ...
    }

    # ...
```

#### view

```
def create(request, author_id):
    author = get_object_or_404(Author, pk=author_id)
    form = BookForm(request.POST or None, initial={'author': author.id})
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
```

So this will allow you to use Django form validation and have db constraints for `IDs` to make sure you will put valid data to the database.

Comment: This question is about "[creating] a form which passes the currently logged-in user". Your code doesn't address that nor prevents users from pretending to be another user by changing the hidden field value. Hence your answer is both incorrect and insecure.